# Is it possible to use a slicer to copy a pivot table to a new sheet for each unique Value

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I need to give each employee a pivot table displaying their work stats, as I cant have employees seeing each others stats I need to make a separate workbook for each employee.

I would like to use a VBA macro to use the slicer for employees to generate there sheet witch I can then use to forward to the relevant employee.
Im still new to using VBA and am unsure of how to make said formula.

Comment: As you can imagine there is not nearly enough information in this question to say more than "yes, it's possible". BUT, keep in mind, if you want the employee to use the slicer which generates the workbooks then the employee also have access to all data. Even if you hide sheets, have a separate workbook with the data, whatever, the employee can just open the VBA editor and see where your code gets the data from. I STRONGLY ADVICE AGAINST THIS. I would say, you generate all the workbooks/sheets from your computer and email them with a macro to each employee. That is more inline with current laws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a button in the ribbon PivotTable Analzye > PivotTable > Options > Show Report Filter Pages that will create a new sheet with a copy of the pivot table filtered to each employee.

But as another user commented, if you just sent the Pivot Tables to the users, they would still be able to see everyone's data.